# How to pass value from activity to fragment in android

Tags: android

How can I get a value(String) from activity and then use it in Fragment?
errors are occurred

fragment.java

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String strtext = getArguments().getString("edttext");
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user_info,
            container, false);

    return rootView;
}
```

activity.java

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("edttext", "From Activity");
UserInfoFragment fragobj = new UserInfoFragment();
fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
```

Comment: What are the errors that you are seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is a `NullPointerException`, correct?

This is because you read the arguments (in the fragment's constructor):

```
String strtext = getArguments().getString("edttext");
```

before you assign them (in activity after the fragment's constructor has already been called):

```
fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
```

Keep the constructor simple. Best solution is to create a static factory method `newInstance(String edttext)` according to this guide https://stackoverflow.com/a/9245510/2444099 like so:

```
public static UserInfoFragment newInstance(String edttext) {
    UserInfoFragment myFragment = new UserInfoFragment();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("edttext", edttext);
    myFragment.setArguments(args);

    return myFragment;
}
```

Then use this factory method instead of constructor whenever you need to obtain a new fragment instance.

Answer (score 1):

This is what's happening in your current code:

1. You create the Fragment
2. In the `onCreateView()` method, you get the arguments
3. You set the arguments in your Activity.

In other words, you're calling the arguments *before* you've set them.  As per the Fragment Documentation, you should be using a static method to instantiate your Fragments.  It would look something like the following.

In your Fragment class, add this code

```
/**
 * Create a new instance of UserInfoFragment, initialized to
 * show the text in str.
 */
public static MyFragment newInstance(String str) {
    MyFragment f = new MyFragment();

    // Supply index input as an argument.
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("edttext", str);
    f.setArguments(args);

    return f;
}
```

And now, in your Activity, do the following:

```
//Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
//bundle.putString("edttext", "From Activity");
//UserInfoFragment fragobj = new UserInfoFragment();
//fragobj.setArguments(bundle);

UserInfoFragment fragobj = UserInfoFragment.newInstance("From Activity");
```

Notice how now, you don't even need to create a Bundle and set it in your Activity class, it is handled by the static `newInstance()` method.